# Camera turns black when clicking back (QR Code)

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, qr-code

I have an app which used the camera for scanning a QR code. Everything works fine when I open the app and go to the QR reader. Once I scan the code, the information is sent to another activity, but once I tap the back button, the camera turns black (see below) and I can't the picture anymore. So somehow resuming the activity stops the camera.

[image]

I have tried to scan the code even with it blank, as I thought it might be only a screen issue, but it is not. But if I leave the activity and come back, it will resume. The Logcat doesn't show any problem, just registers the event in Firebase. Can anyone help me to figure out if it is a hardware problem or if it is bad code? Or is it a normal behavior that needs an activity restart?

The Java file for the QR scanning is given below:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class CodQR extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
  private static final int ID_UL_MEU_PENTRU_PERMISIA_DE_CAMERA = 1000;
  private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cod_qr);
  }

  public void scan() {
    zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(zXingScannerView);
    zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    zXingScannerView.startCamera();

  }

  @Override
  public void handleResult(Result result) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String MyText = result.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(CodQR.this, Qr_Results.class);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, MyText);
    startActivity(intent);
    zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
  }
  //Permissions

  public void CheckPermissionsCamera(View view) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Insufficient permissions.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[] {
          Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        },
        ID_UL_MEU_PENTRU_PERMISIA_DE_CAMERA
      );
    } else {
      scan();
    }
  }


  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case ID_UL_MEU_PENTRU_PERMISIA_DE_CAMERA:
        {
          if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
            // daca grantResults e gol, a dat cancel
            Toast.makeText(this, "You didn't accept the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```
public class Qr_Results extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr_results);
    TextView myText = findViewById(R.id.Text_Qr_Results);
    //Get Intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //Get the string value of the intent
    String text = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    //Set text to TextView
    myText.setText(text);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
  }
  public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
  }
}
```

I can post also the layouts, but I don't think they are relevant. Is there something in the code that might trigger this behavior? Or should I add something to restart the camera?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the sample code in the [barcodescanner repo](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner), you should stop your camera preview in your `CodQR` activity's `onPause()` method.

This is because camera resources need to be released when the activity is paused and no longer in the foreground. When you go to your `Qr_Results` activity, the `CodQR` activity is only paused and not releasing the camera. This is why the preview doesn't restart when you hit the back button. It is good practice to always release an activity's resources when they're no longer needed.

Try adding a call to `stopCamera()` in the `CodQR` activity to see if that solves the issue:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually did that and then disable it because it was crashing when I was going back. So by removing this, I got rid of that crash, but I have this current problem. So with onPause = crash, without onPause = black screen. Is there any other way one can optimize this part?

Comment: @CuriousPaul What does the crash log say?

Comment: Actually, it does the same. I uncommented it and it have the same behavior.  No error though. I have this in my Logcat:  `Connection attempt already in progress 
 Activity resumed, time: 2968307003
Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=7904, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Qr_Results, firebase_screen_id(_si)
Connection attempt already in progress`

Comment: No crash though

Comment: @CuriousPaul Where are you calling your `CheckPermissionsCamera()` method? It should be called in the `CodQR` activity's `onResume()` method. That way when the activity resumes after the back button is pressed, the camera will be restarted with the `scan()` method. You should still stop the camera in `onPause()`. You also might be able to remove the call to `resumeCameraPreview()` since you don't really need to restart it there with the call in `onResume()`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying now with onResume(). I'm applying `public void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); 
        zXingScannerView.startCamera();
    }`

Comment: I get `Unable to resume activity {package.CodQR}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: You need to make sure that you're initializing your `zXingScannerView` before calling any methods on it. My suggestion is to call your `CheckPermissionsCamera()` in `onResume()`. That way when the activity resumes it will check that it still has camera permissions and then will set up the `zXingScannerView` and begin scanning with your `scan()` method. So try something like `public void onResume() { super.onResume(); CheckPermissionsCamera(); }`

Comment: Thank you for staying with me on this @MleChef. I appreciate this. I have restarted my phone because it was on for a long time. Now the Pause I get this `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {package_name.CodQR}: java.lang.NullPointerException`, and the app crashes